# Hiding rows dynamically based on if statement VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me out with the following:

I am trying to dynamically hide rows based on values on another worksheet. However, I am getting the error "Next without For" but I am also uncertain as to the functionality of my code. I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me out here.

```
Sub Update()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 8 To 22
    If Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0 Then
    Sheets("2").Rows("x - 3 : x - 3").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Sheets("2").Rows("x - 3 : x - 3").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End if
Next x

End Sub
```

EDIT (SOLUTION)
The code that works is:

```
Sub Update()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 8 To 22
    If Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0 Then
    Sheets("2").Rows((x - 3) & ":" & (x - 3)).Hidden = True
    Else
    Sheets("2").Rows((x - 3) & ":" & (x - 3)).Hidden = False
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Or

```
Dim x As Long

For x = 8 To 22
    Sheets("2").Rows(x - 3).Hidden = Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0
Next x
```

Comment: you forget to type `end if` after if statement

Comment: I see.. Thanks! However, I still get a type mismatch for: `Sheets("2").Rows("x - 3 : x - 3").Select`. Is it even possible to define it in this way?

Comment: I think you need to .activate the sheet before using select.

Comment: "x-3:x-3" will not be interpreted as "5:5". it should be (x-3) & ":" & (x-3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Anything between quotes will be considered as a string. So `"x-3:x-3"` is a string. As @DS_London mentioned use `(x - 3) & ":" & (x - 3)`
2. Having said that `Sheets("2").Rows((x - 3) & ":" & (x - 3)).Hidden` can be written `Sheets("2").Rows(x - 3).Hidden`

Alternative way to achieve what you want

```
Dim x As Long

For x = 8 To 22
    Sheets("2").Rows(x - 3).Hidden = Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0
Next x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this part to simplify the code, since you don't have to select the worksheet:

```
 If Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0 Then
    Sheets("2").Rows("x - 3 : x - 3").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
```

To:

```
If Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0 Then
Sheets("2").Rows(x).Hidden = True
Else
```

Comment: `Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0` will return True or False - which is what the Hidden property wants.  You could just place it there instead.  It seems a blank cell also returns True for 0 as well though.  Taking that into consideration you could use `Sheets("2").Rows(x).Hidden = (Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value = 0 And Sheets("1").Cells(x, 3).Value <> "")`

Comment: ya, it is getting too advance, he may not understand lol.

Comment: Thanks Darren for the more comprehensive explanation!